# How to Set send from in mail session

Tags: java, email, session, jakarta-mail

I want to send a mail to a recipient as the reset password is clicked.
The mail is being send correct , but the send from address is like myname@SystemName
How can I set the send from address ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the setFrom() method:

```
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sendingaddress@company.com"));
```

[JavaDoc reference](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Message.html#setFrom%28javax.mail.Address%29)